# Music stutters on ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, music

I'm a big music lover and on my previous phone which was a Galaxy Y with Gingerbread I listen to a lot of stuff, and I've never had a problem.

I bought a new phone, a rebranded Innos D9 which has ICS installed. I tried using my favorite music player on it, UberMusic, but I found out the music stutters for a few seconds every few seconds. I tried other players, and so far only TTPod reduces it so that I'm not bothered by it. I was even told that PowerAmp doesn't have this problem, so I tried it. At first I thought everything's okay, then the thing screeched. Also, the stuttering is more likely to happen when the screen is off and you turn it on while the audio is playing.

I've done some research and found this thread on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22763). It seems that this problem is on ICS. Now my question is, what can be done to fix this permanently? Is there an app or music player out there that totally doesn't have stuttering for ICS or should I root my phone and do something?

Important Update:

I forgot to mention that the stuttering doesn't appear when I'm listening to the FM radio or when I'm watching videos. Does this mean this could be an OS related problem? Like a setting in the mp3 buffer or something?

Comment: Is this happening on certain encoded mp3's? - see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22763#c5)

Comment: Maybe try upgrading ICS? ( you did not mention exact version?) from the Google Code issue, its apparently fixed in a later version of ICS (4.0.4)

Comment: There's commits made to the frameworks according to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22444#c80) so it could well be your ICS is < 4.0.4?

Comment: My phone is 4.0.4, and about the bitrate I tried two songs to validate the stuttering: Myth by Beach House which is indeed 320kbps but it also appears on Pink Moon by Nick Drake which is 175 kbps. Is there a later version of ICS? I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to update unless the manufacturer of my phone says so. Also, on that same page on a higher version of ICS(I think), the error persists. Cite: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22444#c89

Comment: last ICS version was 4.0.5 IIRC... then jumped up to JellyBean 4.1.x and 4.2.x

Comment: Oh man, guess I have to wait for a Jellybean rom.

Comment: Either that or try roll your own ROM with the fixes/commits in place - that's a challenge :D

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will try that... once I learn Android development. Thanks anyway, I'll take it as a challenge! :)